# Why did this query change work?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I ended up scrapping the part of the WHERE clause that was giving me issues, but initially I got this query working by doing something that didn't make sense to me at all, and was hoping someone could shine some light on what is going on here.  The entire query and function are below, but I'm not sure all of that is necessary

So this query was previously working and this WHERE clause is still being used successfully in another query.  Now multiple functions are used in this line of the where clause, however if I just use the portion starting with ModifiedStartDate the query works fine.  So it seems like the issue is with ModifiedDate.  The portion of the WHERE clause that was giving us issues was:

```
and ModifiedDate(r.EXPIRATION_DATE, ModifiedStartDate(r.COMMENCEMENT_DATE, 
PaySched_MaxFreq(r.RE_CONTRACT_KEY))) > #1/1/2019#
```

The query was failing with the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".    So just doing some testing I ended up adding the following portion to the WHERE clause:

```
and r.RE_CONTRACT_KEY NOT IN (1)
```

And then the query worked?!?!  **I really don't get how adding this line magically resolved a data type mismatch error.**  There is no RE_CONTRACT_KEY = 1 so it's not bad data or something.

I did some testing and took the ModifiedDate function and put that into the select clause and it worked fine.  I also added another field to the SELECT clause using the DATEADD function to make sure the function result was still being treated as a date, and it was.  Query is below and the function is below that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ....
FROM ((((((PAYMENT_LINE_ITEM AS pli 
INNER JOIN PAYMENT_SCHEDULE AS tps ON pli.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_KEY = 
ps.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_KEY) 
INNER JOIN RECONTRACT AS r ON pli.RE_CONTRACT_KEY = r.RE_CONTRACT_KEY) 
INNER JOIN Conversion_ProductCategory AS cpc ON cpc.Value = pli.PAYMENT_TYPE) 
INNER JOIN ManualEntry AS me ON me.LeaseID = r.RE_CONTRACT_ID) 
LEFT JOIN Mapping_CostCenter AS mcc ON mcc.CostCenter = me.CostCenter) 
INNER JOIN PIW_Exclusions AS pe ON pe.RE_CONTRACT_ID = r.RE_CONTRACT_ID) 
LEFT JOIN FacilityCode_Address_xRef AS fca ON fca.[Facility Code] = 
mcc.placecode & "-" & mcc.placecodedescription
WHERE pli.PAYMENT_TYPE  in ("rent","storage","parking")  
    and ModifiedDate(r.EXPIRATION_DATE, 
    ModifiedStartDate(r.COMMENCEMENT_DATE, 
    PaySched_MaxFreq(r.RE_CONTRACT_KEY))) > #1/1/19#
    and PE.Reason = "rent extension" 
    and r.RE_CONTRACT_KEY NOT IN (1) 'New line added that made query work
```

And the function:

```
Public Function ModifiedDate(DateToModify As Date, DateToCompare As Date) As 
Date

Select Case DateToModify
Case #2/28/2000#, #2/28/2004#, #2/28/2008#, #2/28/2012#, #2/28/2016#, 
#2/28/2020#, #2/28/2024#, #2/28/2028#, #2/28/2032#, #2/28/2036#, #2/28/2040#, 
#2/28/2044#, #2/28/2048#
    DateToModify = DateAdd("d", 1, DateToModify)
End Select

If DatePart("d", DateAdd("d", 1, DateToModify)) = DatePart("d", 
DateToCompare) Then

    ModifiedDate = DateAdd("d", 1, DateToModify)

Else
    ModifiedDate = DateToModify
End If

End Function
```

If you're curious the final working WHERE clause is:

```
WHERE pli.PAYMENT_TYPE  in ("rent","storage","parking") 
    and r.EXPIRATION_DATE > #1/1/19#
    and PE.Reason = "rent extension"
```

Comment: I can't really tell you specifically why you're seeing this abnormal behavior, but a couple of things I can point out. 1. You really should be using parameters to pass those dates rather than using crazy Access SQL date formats to accomplish that goal. 2. There are some funky things going on with your parathesis for the `ModifiedDate` function in your where clause. This could be because that's what the `ModifiedStartDate` requires, I don't really have that information though.

Comment: @Jiggle32 1. I'm not sure what you're saying about using parameters.  The query is just a regular query, it's not created or updated through VBA.  I know that SELECT CASE is ugly in the ModifiedDate function, but it still seemed like the easiest solution.  2.  It is a little funky but the parentheses are correct.  PaySched_MaxFreq takes 1 parameter and both date functions take 2 parameters.

Comment: Can't tell what you are doing, except that it seems that you are overcomplicating the task, indeed regarding the date handling. However, the cause for such errors are often invalid field values like _Null_.